# number of requests required to write/read a single parquet file with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, request

I have a pyspark etl pipeline running in aws.  we're seeing a large number of get/put/list/head requests when writting/reading from s3.  So we're trying to figure out which part of our pipeline might be responsible.  I'm wondering how many get/put/list/head requests are involved in pyspark code writting a single parquet file, for example with an action like the one below:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet('some_path/')
```

I know this code could possibly write many parquet files, but I figure if I know the number of get/put/list/head requests involved in writting one parquet file I can estimate based on the total number of parquet files the code wrote.

similarly I'd like to know the total number of get/put/list/head requests involved in reading one parquet file

```
df=sqlContext.read.parquet('some_path/')
```